# MongoDB C# driver fast on take(1) but slow on take(2)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, mongodb

I've been playing around with the MongoDB C# driver for the first time and I'm finding some strange results in performance.
When I query a collection with 3 million records with ordering and .Take(1) the reponse is nearly instantanious (3ms.). But when I .Take(2) on the same query it takes up to 10 seconds.
The right index is in place and it's a very simple collection with test data.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();

var database = server.GetDatabase("db_name");
var collection = database.GetCollection<MyType>("collection_name");

var query = from c in collection.AsQueryable<MyType>()
            where c.SearchString.Contains(searchString)
            orderby c.SearchString
            select c.SearchString;

List<string> results = query.Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: I wonder why `take(1)` is fast: `Contains()` translates to a regex, and non-rooted regex queries can't use an index, so they are pretty slow. Could you supply the results of `explain()`?

Comment: I've never used MongoDB, but my guess: `OrderBy+Take(1)` is translated to something like `Max`(or `Min`).

Comment: Use a debugging tool (not sure what's relevant for mongodb) to see what query is actually being executed on the DB in either case.  If there is a much more effective translation of one over the other (i.e. if there's an operation to take the first, but not to take just two, so the `Take(2)` is just pulling all of the data and filtering in the C# application) then that could be the issue.

Comment: Visit http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ page and as mentioned above, try to profile your query in order to get an actual query being performed on the db.

Comment: Try to search for a string that does not exist in the collection. I bet that the Take(1) will be slow for that scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MongoDB C# Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/#supported-where-clauses) will translate a string.Contains method into a regex. So `c.SearchStringContains("abc")` will get translated to:

```
{ SearchString : /abc/ }
```

However, MongoDB can only use indexes on a "starts with" regex. Quoting from the the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/):

> $regex can only use an index efficiently when the regular expression
>   has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is a
>   case-sensitive match. Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/
>   match equivalent strings, they have different performance
>   characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an
>   appropriate index exists; however, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower.
>   /^a/ can stop scanning after matching the prefix.

I suspect that if you use the [explain command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/explain/) on your query you'll see that your index containing the `SearchString` field is not being used effectively.

I believe that the reason why the `Take(1)` is faster than a `Take(2)` is likely to be that your `SearchString` index is used only for the sort portion of the query, and the first match occurs very early in the B-Tree walk. The second occurrence is likely to occur much later in the B-Tree walk, resulting in a much higher `nscan` (the number of documents the server scans looking for a result).

To work around this issue and be able to use the index, I'd suggest using either the [keyword search approach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-keyword-search/); or alternatively if you have v2.4+ you can try the [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/) feature.